# CMake compile options for compile test only

Tags: cmake, multiprocessing, cross-compiling

I am using CMake to cross compile a C project for an embedded (heterogeneous) multi-core system. The compiler takes an mandatory argument (`-t<type>`, the target type). This flag has to be set to pass CMake's compiler test. I am adding this flag in a toolchain file as follows:

```
add_compile_options(-tMYPLATFORMTYPE)
```

The problem with this approach is, all project files will be compiled with this flag. Is there a way to configure compile flags for the test compilation only, without affecting the main project configuration? (Note: Within the project different files shall have different values for this flag.)

What I am looking for is something like:

```
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_COMPILE_OPTIONS "-tMYPLATFORMTYPE")
```

---

I could disabled the compile test, but I would prefer to keep it.

Comment: `all project files will be compiled with this flag` - do you compile other files for a different platform?

Comment: @KamilCuk Kind of, it is a multi core system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the [IN_TRY_COMPILE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/IN_TRY_COMPILE.html) property and set the flag for try-compile configurations only:

```
get_property(IS_IN_TRY_COMPILE GLOBAL PROPERTY IN_TRY_COMPILE)
if(IS_IN_TRY_COMPILE)
    add_compile_options(-tMYPLATFORMTYPE)
endif()
```